# Fully Qualified Names from SQL Server in SAS

Tags: sql-server, sas

I need to be able to specify the schema that I want to access in SAS. I have used a connection string with the following schema=?? but SAS will not let me select or print the contents of any object in the named schema. Has anyone been able to write a PROC SQL statement selecting objects in a schema other than dbo?

Thank you,

Comment: For some connection options the schema is case sensative.  Check that first.

Comment: It may be persisting permissions too. Also, try using pass-through to confirm you can do what you're wanting to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SAS does not use fully quallified names from the SQL server but you can direct SAS to a specific schema. The following is an example that uses a libname as connection to a 2008 SQL Server.

```
proc print data=myDBconn.v_Lots (SCHEMA=SAS);
   WHERE Study_ID IS NOT NULL;
run;

proc print data=myDBconn.Drugs (SCHEMA=Pharmacy);
   where _drug_id=1;
run;

proc sql;
   create table myTest.drugs as ;
   (SELECT * FROM myDbconn.drugs (SCHEMA=Pharmacy));
quit;
```